# Asian Characters Support in Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, multilingual

My application is currently being used by English users only and now we are planing to launch the application in China, Japan, Korean and other Asian countries, hence like to build the Asian language support in it,  This should allow users to enter data in their languages and that would be saved in our system as well.

I read somewhere on net that i can use the devise fonts to support the same, I modified our style sheets to add '_sans' besides the current fontNames, I am now able to enter data in Asian languages but i observed that the UI  look and feel has degraded, the fonts are not sharp anymore and they seem hazy.

Am i doing something wrong here? Please advise how to fix this problem, I want to support Asian Characters but would like to maintain system's current look and feel.

Any help would be great!

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed an Asian font which is more appealing and sharp, there are free-for-commercial-use ones over the web.
Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Thanks Gal, I am using Flash Builder, Can you suggest some free-for-commercial-use fonts? Are you suggesting to individually embed the specific asian font or some universal font file? We have to support Chinese (Simplified & Traditional), Japanese & Korean languages at this moment but have to make sure that the current system look and feel is still maintained. Currently, We use Arial & Verdana fonts in our application.

Comment: A universal font to support all these languages would be quite difficult to find on a free-for-commercial-use basis, furthermore it should keep your application look & feel - so I guess being picky for each specific font is a good solution.

Comment: Japanese free-for-commercial-use fonts: http://sourceforge.jp/magazine/09/04/27/0313213/3 http://blog.4galaxy.net/56.html http://www.hakusyu.com/download/kyokan.html http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Japanese.html

Comment: Do u think embedding the individual fonts like Chinese, Korean, Japanese into the swf is a good idea? Wouldn't it increase the swf size and we'll endup in adding n-number of font files to swf. Are you aware of any known issues with appending the "_sans" at the last of fontFamily style? one thing that i am still unable to figure out is why is this addition of '_sans' changing my current look and feel with English language. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding additional fonts will increase the file size. Haven't met known issues regarding _sans. "Veranda" could be the problem as it is a sans-serif font.

Comment: Thanks Gal, I am planing to use the existing verdana font for the english language so that the current behavior for the english user doesn't change and embed the limited range based unicode characters from the Arial MS Unicode font file to support the Chinese, Japanese & Korean languages. I see the improved look and feel plus the ability to enter the asian chars. Do you foresee any issues with this approach?